# Why can't I get the last insert ID in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysqli, last-insert-id

I have a function that creates a course. I am trying to get the Last Insert ID but it doesn't work:

```
public  function createCourse()
{
    require "/mysqli_connect.php";
    $course_q = "INSERT INTO course (....) VALUES (.....)";

    $course_r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $course_q);
    $course_n = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
    if($course_n == 1)
    {
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
        return true;
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    return false;
}
```

This is the function to retrieve the last insert ID that I created in the same class as the function createCourse:

```
public function getLastInsertID()
{
    require "/../mysqli_connect.php";

    $course_q= "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";

    $course_r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $course_q);
    $course_n = mysqli_num_rows($course_r);

    //var_dump($course_n);
    if($course_n)
    {
        $c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($course_r);
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

        return $c;
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    return NULL;
}
```

This is how I call the functions:

```
require "/mysqli_connect.php";
$course = new Course();
$c = $course->createCourse();
$id = $course->getLastInsertID();
var_dump($id);
```

`"$id"` is always `"int(0)"`

I've also tried:

```
require "/mysqli_connect.php";
$course = new Course();
$c = $course->createCourse();
**$id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);**
```

and I've also tried:

```
$course_q= "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() from course";
```

but that doesn't work as well. Can you guys see what the problem is? :( The function createCourse itself is fine. It creates what I need and it's there in the database but I can't get the last insert id.

Comment: do a `var_dump($mysqli)` and post here

Comment: You close the mysql result resource before it can be used for getLastInsertID, maybe this is the cause.

Comment: I think your link to mysqli is null..

Comment: Did one of the posts answer your question? If so, could you accept it for future visitors' benefit? Thanks! (See [How do I ask a question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the proper way to retrieve the insert id with MySQLi is to use `mysqli_insert_id()`, since you're doing an associative fetch, you would need a column alias for the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

```
 $course_q= "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS insert_id";

 // Later...
 $c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($course_r);
 echo $c['insert_id'];
```

However, that isn't going to work because you have already closed the connection with `mysqli_close()` in your `createCourse()` function.  Instead, get the insert id inside `createCourse()` and return it.

```
public  function createCourse()
{
    // Note: You should not establish the connection in each function call.
    // it only needs to be done once per script, and you can pass the connection
    // into the class constructor or into methods that use it.
    require "/mysqli_connect.php";
    $course_q = "INSERT INTO course (....) VALUES (.....)";

    $course_r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $course_q);
    $course_n = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
    if($course_n == 1)
    {
        // Get the insert id before closing the connection
        $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);


        // Note that there probably isn't a good reason to explicitly close the
        // connection here.  It will be closed when the script terminates.
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

        // And return it.
        return $insert_id;
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    return false;
}

require "/mysqli_connect.php";
$course = new Course();
$c = $course->createCourse();
echo $c;
// $c contains the id
```

#### Design classes to use one common connection:

The class receives a connection in its constructor.

```
// Make classes accept the connection as a param:
class MyClass
{
  // property to hold the connection object
 public $db;

  // constructor receives the connection
  public function __construct($connection) {
    $this->db = $connection;
  }
  
  // Methods call it as $this->db
  public function createCourse() {
    $course_r = mysqli_query($this->db, $course_q);
  }
      
}
```

Include the connection only once on the controlling script

```
require_once("/mysqli_connect.php");
// $mysqli is now defined...

// Pass it into the constructor
$course = new MyClass($mysqli);
```

Comment: You mentioned that it isn't a good reason to close the connection there before I return. When should I close it then? All my classes which are essentially model classes are closing mysqli then returning. Have I messed everything up? :(

Comment: @JohnathanAu You haven't messed up, you can just remove opening and closing from all classes. Opening and closing the connection is a slow and resource-intensive process, so it is best to do it only once unless you have a good reason to close it down. Typically it is opened once at the top of the script, and you can pass the connection into your class constructors.  You don't usually need to close it manually - the script will do that when execution finishes.

Comment: Hmm, I better change this ASAP then since the system will be handling loads of people from all of the world. I'm more shocked about why my supervisor never mentioned this to me! 

To reiterate, should I ever only be using one, and only one connection per run time?

Comment: @JohnathanAu, there are times when more than one connection is necessary (e.g. connecting to two separate databases), but you should typically only need *one* connection to any *one* database in any give script. There are exceptions, of course, but you'll probably know when you come across a circumstance that is an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you have multiple connections to the database, and last inserted ID is tracked on a per-connection basis.

***Note:** You should **not** connect to the same database every time you run a query. Simply connect at the beginning of the script, and close at the end. Connecting and disconnecting constantly will cause your script to run extremely slowly, especially with more queries.*

Also, the last inserted ID is available via MySQLi's [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you're closing the mysqli connection at the end of `createCourse()`.

Either don't make `createCourse()` responsible for closing the connection (move it elsewhere) or have `createCourse()` return the insert ID on success (or `false` on failure)